# Can one be using two nested synchronized blocks in order to lock two cells of an array for atomic operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a class `Repository` which allocates resources represented as values of the `cells` array field. The method moves the resources from one cell to another.

I need to make sure that when we move resources from one cell to another, no other move operations can be performed on the cells in question. That is if a cell (origin cell or destination cell) participates in `move` operation, we must wait until the current operation completes before we perform another `move` operation on those cells. There should be no limitation on performing `move` on different pairs of cells in parallel, for example, `move(cells[1], cells[2], 5)` and `move(cells[4], cells[7], 9)` can be performed in parallel.

I thought to use two nested `synchronized` blocks in order to protect both origin and destination cell. I don't think we need to use `wait`/`notifyAll` because we're using `synchronized` anyway.

Am I on the right track?

This is the code (`moveOriginal` is the original method and `moveSynchronized` is the protected one:

```
public class Repository {
    private Integer[] cells;

    public Repository(int size, int initialValue) {
        cells = new Integer[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cells[i] = initialValue;
        }
    }

    public void moveOriginal(int from, int to, int amount) {
        if(cells[from] >= amount) {
            cells[from] = cells[from] - amount;
            cells[to] = cells[to] + amount;
        }
    }

    public void moveSynchronized(int from, int to, int amount) {
        synchronized(cells[from]) {
            synchronized (cells[to]) {
                if(cells[from] >= amount) {
                    cells[from] = cells[from] - amount;
                    cells[to] = cells[to] + amount;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, that `moveSynchronized(X,Y,...)` and `moveSynchronized(Y,X,...)` invoked at the same time will cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. For this to work you would need to lock on the array itself, preventing parallel operations.

`Integer` is immutable, meaning `cells[to] = cells[to] + amount` puts a different object there, instead of modifying the `Integer` in it. This will cause problems when `synchronized(cells[to])` is referring to different objects at different times.

A simplest way to fix this would be to make a `Object[] lockArray = new Object[size];` initialized with `Objects` and synchronize on those. They won't change during your business logic.

In any case you need nested `synchronized` scopes. What you also need to do is [define an order](http://wiki.c2.com/?OrderedLocks), e.g. always first synchronize on the smaller value. Otherwise you'll get a deadlock when multiple threads try to do something like `move(1, 2); move(2, 1);` at the same time.

```
public void moveSynchronized(int from, int to, int amount) {
    if(from == to || from < 0 || to < 0 || from > cells.length || to.cells.length)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad values ! " + from + ", " + to);

    // Lock1 is always smaller and locked first
    int lock1 = from < to ? from : to;
    int lock2 = from < to ? to : from;

    synchronized(locks[lock1]) {
        synchronized (locks[lock2]) {
            if(cells[from] >= amount) {
                cells[from] = cells[from] - amount;
                cells[to] = cells[to] + amount;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use the `Object` array as you suggested would I still use nested `synchronized` blocks?

Comment: this is an excellent catch that you noticed the scenario of `move(1,2)` vs `move(2,1)`! finally I don't need to use `wait`/`notifyAll` here right? because we don't need to delay the execution of any threads, we just want to get the results of the calculations ASAP and `synchronized` already takes care of protection

Comment: Also, now that you're not using `cells` as lock objects, you should make them `int` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: @Yos no there's no reason to use `wait/notify`.

Comment: if my cells array was represented by a non-immutable type, could I use those objects as locks in that case?

Comment: @Yos yes, if you used an array of `AtomicIntegers` (not for their atomicity, but for their mutability) they could be used as locks. Although I really wouldn't do that. Unless you're talking about arrays of thousands of elements, separate locks won't be an issue. With large arrays I would use a striped lock.

Comment: @Yos, Here's something deeper for you to think about:  Even if you implement a strategy to prevent the deadlock, what would it mean for thread B to call `move(1,2)` while thread A already is in a call to `move(2,1)`?  Suppose the locking works, and thread A's call completes before thread B's call can begin.  What did thread A know about the state of the array before it called `move(2,1)`?  What will thread A _assume_ about the state of the array afterward?  Will the assumption(s) still be correct if thread B can sneak in at any time and do `move(1,2)` without thread A knowing about it?

Comment: @jameslarge I'm not sure what you mean with your questions regarding the state of the array before thread was called.

Comment: @Yos He's talking about whether it makes logically sense to have two threads perform operations that cancel each other, but that's not the issue here. The issue is that no matter what the order, you will always have a consistent result instead of race conditions.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues with this approach.

1. `synchronized` locks on the value of the `cell[x]`, an `Integer`, so as soon as you do this

   ```
   cells[from] = cells[from] - amount;
   ```

   synchronizing on `cells[from]` would be locking a different object.
2. `Integer` interns objects representing small values. Locking on a shared object like that may lock you out of an entirely wrong cell.
3. Availability of shared `Integer` objects goes beyond your thread. Another thread can obtain shared integers on which you synchronize, and lock you out of `cells` without gaining access to private data structures of your class.

If you want cell-level locking, create an array of objects that would be used specifically for locking the corresponding cells; do not lock on cell values.

Comment: @Yos Right, you would need two nested `synchronized` blocks, just on different objects.